# com.apple.eawt.Application not working after obfuscation

Tags: java, windows, macos, obfuscation

I have written an application in Java for both Mac OSx and Windows, but I've developed it on Windows. Therefore I used `java.lang.reflect.*` in order to implement the 'About' and 'Quit' handler without receiving exceptions.

I've exported it as an Executable Jar and everything works fine on both operating systems. However, I want to obfuscate the application and  I'm using ProGaurd to do so. I've specified  the necessary libraries for it to work on Windows (rt.jar, jsse.jar, jce.jar) and it still does work fine on Windows, however ProGaurd is telling me that there is two unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces, and the obfuscated application no longer works properly on Mac (the About and Quit Handler don't work).

I read somewhere that the `ui.jar` was required, so I copied it accross from my Mac and specified it in ProGaurd but that did not seem to solve the problem! Any solutions appreciated then...

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I have now used AppleJavaExtensions in order to implement the handlers using `com.apple.eawt.Application` rather than reflect. However, I'm still getting the exact same problem! Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
package ap;
import com.apple.eawt.AboutHandler;
import com.apple.eawt.AppEvent;
import com.apple.eawt.AppEvent.QuitEvent;
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
import com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler;
import com.apple.eawt.QuitResponse;
import com.gui.Tabs;

public class xa implements AboutHandler, QuitHandler {

    // Constructor to register/install the necessary handler's
    public xa(){
        Application.getApplication().setAboutHandler(this);
        Application.getApplication().setQuitHandler(this);
    }

    // Implemented method to catch the About menu item
    @Override
    public void handleAbout(AppEvent.AboutEvent e) {
        Tabs.switchAbout();

    }

    // Implemented method to catch the Quit menu item
    @Override
    public void handleQuitRequestWith(QuitEvent arg0, QuitResponse arg1) {
        Tabs.quit();        
    }
}
```

AND I am using the ProGuard GUI to obfuscate my application. In Obsfucation 'tab' at the bottom I've added class `ap.xa` and specified that it extends/implements `AboutHandler, QuitHandler`. I've also added the Class `com.gui.Tabs` but it the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opps, I've solved the problem...** And I only made a silly mistake

Because I'm using the ProGuard GUI, I failed to see the "Class members" part in the addition screen. Therefore, whilst ProGuard wasn't obfuscating the class itself, it was obfuscating the methods, hence the listeners not working. So, I've ended up 'keeping' `ap.xa` and all it's methods (the class containing the actually listeners), and `com.apple.**` (the JavaAppleExtensions package)

However, there is still one thing occurring. When I run the obfuscated JAR file from Terminal I receive the following output:

```
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andy$ java -jar /Users/Andy/Desktop/YLIT\ Final\ 2.jar
Jun  9 20:50:29 Andrews-MacBook-Pro.local java[959] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun  9 20:50:29 Andrews-MacBook-Pro.local java[959] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun  9 20:50:29 Andrews-MacBook-Pro.local java[959] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jun  9 20:50:29 Andrews-MacBook-Pro.local java[959] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [Apple Java Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/Introduction/Intro.html).

Using the Apple Java Extensions, you could develop on Windows without using `java.lang.reflect.*` classes, and maybe it will be easier for ProGuard.

Comment: Thank you - that looks like it could do the job but I'm not sure how to take advantage of it in Eclipse. Is it possible you could provide a link with instructions on how to set the 'about' and 'quit' handler with it or something please?

Comment: You can consult Apple documentation: [Java Development Guide for Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development).

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a bit stupid here but I can't see anything about Apple Java Extensions or About/Quit Handlers on that page (or any of the links on it)

Comment: I have  found out how to use the AppleJavaExtensions to install the handlers with `Application`, but ProGuard still breaks the program, even if I obfuscate on Mac!

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you tell ProGuard not to obfuscate the classes that implement the About and Quit handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-dontoptimize` option. Some methods are removed when they have "no effect." And executing ProGuard on Windows... for Mac. Or a dumb alternative: try obfuscating on a Mac and deliver two versions.

Comment: qSorry for the slow reply and thank you for your answer! I've just been 'looking around' ProGuard (on my Mac aswell) again. It seems that if anything is done, at all, to the wrong classes the listeners no long work. The problem is: I don't know which classes to keep! At the minute, for testing purposes, ProGuard is only obfuscating but I figured that if I could get the handler's to work with obfuscating enabled the same classes to keep would apply for shrinking and optimising. So, all I need to know now is which classes are the sensitive ones... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no idea; not doing the Mac. But the [keep](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) options have class specifications with extended wild cards, so `com.apple.*` or something like `*Listener` might do.

Comment: No problem. I gave it to you because although I found the answer myself you pointed me in the right direction. Plus I'd have lost 100 points either way